# having problem with inserting an image into a database

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
    if (uploadimg.PostedFile != null && uploadimg.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {

        string img_id = "1";
        byte[] myimage = new byte[uploadimg.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        HttpPostedFile Image = uploadimg.PostedFile;
        Image.InputStream.Read(myimage, 0, (int)uploadimg.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eclass;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security = true");
        SqlCommand storeimage = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ImageGallery " + "(img_id,image_Size,image_Content) " + " values (@img_id,@imagesize,@image)", myConnection);
        storeimage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id",img_id);
       // storeimage.Parameters.Add("@id",SqlDbType.VarChar,100) = uploadimg.PostedFile.ContentType;
        //storeimage.Parameters.Add('@id',id);
        storeimage.Parameters.Add("@imagesize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999).Value = uploadimg.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        storeimage.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image, myimage.Length).Value = myimage;



        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            storeimage.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

what changes should i make in my c# code so that i can avoid my sql exception of primary key constrain as i hav used my trigger

create trigger trig_image 
on ImageGallery 
After insert 
as begin 
declare @id int;
set @id=1;
update ImageGallery set img_id='img'+cast(@id as varchar(10))
set @id=@id+1; 
end 
go

and columns are img_id varchar(50),image_size bigint,image_content image

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using?? If you're on 2005 or newer: **do not** use datatype `IMAGE` anymore! It's dead - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Comment: so will it work using varbinary(max) cause it previously worked and its giving me an error in img_id and not in image_content ..what changes should i make in my c# code

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL Server will try to convert 'img' to an integer to add `@id` to it.  Change:

```
set img_id = 'img' + @id
```

to

```
set img_id = 'img' + cast(@id as varchar(12))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your Trigger statement.

You have to explicitly convert the `@id` variable to a varchar.

```
declare @id int; 
set @id=1; 

update ImageGallery 
set img_id='img'+ convert(varchar(10), @id)

set @id=@id+1
```

EDIT:

You are probably getting a PK constraint violation because:

- You are trying to update all `img_id`'s rather than the one you have just inserted
- You are always setting the `@id` variable to 1 so each time the trigger runs the `@Id` value will always be 1

Another option would be to change your table structure and have `img_id` as an [integer identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).  This will save you from having to manually calculate the ID as SQL Server will automatically increment the value on each insert.

You can easily add the 'img' prefix before displaying to the client.

e.g

**example select**

```
Select 'img' + convert(varchar(10), img_id) as 'Formatted_Img_id'
from ImageGallery
```

**example update**

```
Update ImageGallery
Set Description = 'blah blah test'
Where img_id = Replace(img_id, 'img','')
```

Comment: yup it worked ..thnxx alot..but now i am not getting ma image_content

Comment: @shweta - I would image it is because 1) You are trying to update all Img_id's in the table rather than only updating the new row. 2) You are setting the @id to 1 so every time the trigger runs it will always try to update the img_id to 1.

Comment: @shweta - Well to be honest I don't see the benefit of having the Trigger anyway as you are passing the img_id from your App and inserting it in to your table in your first SQL statement.

Comment: see the thing is i want my img_id to appears as img1..img2..n so on that is why i am using trigger..so what should i do to avoid this problem

Comment: and i am passing img_id as ma column img_id doesnot accept null values so i have to pass this img_id

Comment: @shweta - Why not change `img_id` to be an `integer` and use an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).  That way you won't have to pass any value to the Insert statement. SQL Server will take care of it for you and whenever you insert a new row it will increment the img_id by 1

Comment: @shweta - using an Identity columns means you can't have the id prefixed with 'img' but you can easily add this if you want to when presenting the data to the client.

Comment: @Shweta - Sorry, your requests are going beyond the scope of the original question. If you have another problem please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is very dangerous..... the code as you have it will update **all rows** in your table `ImageGallery` everytime an insert happens - is that really what you want??

Also - to have a separate column with `img001, img002` etc., I would use a **computed column**:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ImageGallery
  ADD ImageText AS 'img' + CAST(img_id AS VARCHAR(5)) PERSISTED
```

With this, you get a new column called `ImageText` which will hold values `img1`, `img2` and so forth - automatically, without any need for a messy trigger or anything - it just works!

Comment: what you wrote in the question it is what i want...and now i got the answer menas i got my image_id but my image content is not coming now

Comment: @shweta: why do you set the "img_id" yourself?? Just make it an `INT IDENTITY` field and let the database handle the numbering...

Answer (score 0):

What is the date type of the field image_id?

I assume it's of type INT. I recommend using date type varchar.

Comment: in the sense i am using sql server 2005...and datatype of image_content is image...it worked before when i was using it simple..but when i am specifically using img_id it isnt

Comment: @beacon yes i am using varchar